# Adding roles from a DB Table

Tags: c#, .net, wif

Can anyone expalin me how to dynamically ger the Role from a DB table instead of hard coding it in the code.

```
ClaimsIdentity outputIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        outputIdentity.Claims.Add(new Claim(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, principal.Identity.Name));
        outputIdentity.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Manager"));
        outputIdentity.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Country, HttpUtilities.GetProgramIdentifierFromUrl()));
        return outputIdentity;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you storing your Roles?  I presume it is something along the lines of:

```
Create Table Roles
(
RoleId int identity(1,1) Not Null,
RoleName varchar(50) not null
)
```

Why don't you just query the Database to fetch the RoleId and then use the result of the query in your update.

Wouldn't a user have selected the Role somewhere in this process?  Can't you grab the ID or RoleName for their initial selection?

Comment: Sorry Barry I asked the question wrong. Can I add my own members in claimtypes, current the claimtypes class has the following members,
Anonymous
Authentication
AuthorizationDecision
Country
DateOfBirth
DenyOnlySid
Dns
Email
Gender
GivenName
Hash
HomePhone
Locality
MobilePhone
Name
NameIdentifier
OtherPhone
PostalCode
PPID
Rsa
Sid
Spn
StateOrProvince
StreetAddress
Surname
System
Thumbprint
Upn
Uri
Webpage
X500DistinguishedName


Is it possible to add a new member. It is a static class and no way to inherit it.

Comment: Would this be of any use to you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734687.aspx

Comment: Thanks Barry. I will just go with this. Will send you a sample after some time.